# Where can I find libstdc++ header?

Tags: linux, libc, libstdc++

I configure on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have to install libc header and libstdc++ header on computer. After searching, I type the following command line:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

I want to detect whether they were installed successfully. So I type `whereis libc.*` and the shell shows me `libc: /usr/share/man/man7/libc.7.gz` and type `whereis libstdc++.*`; the shell shows me `libstdc++:`.

Even I tried to find answer, I still have no idea whether these two headers were installed successfully.

Comment: Take a look at the `dpkg` utility, it allows to list files contained inside an installed package using the `-L` flag. Start by reading it's manual mage: `man dpkg`.

Comment: before I typed above two command lines, I had typed 'sudo apt-get update'. As for installing libstdc++ header, I also tried 'sudo apt-get install libstdc++'. I also tried other command lines like 'sudo apt-get install build-essential '

Comment: I assume you received an error when trying to install `libstdc++` or `libstdc++6` or similar, since those packages do no exist. But you do not mention any such error. The package you are looking for probably is `libstdc++-6-dev`. Then, after installation, you can use `dpkg -L libstdc++-6-dev` to list the installed files.

Comment: If you are new to this, then probably some graphical frontend to the package management helps a lot, since it allows you to search for packages and read their descriptions. If you do not have a graphical environment then take a look at the `apt-cache` utility: it allows to search through the available packages to find the correct one: `apt-cache search libstdc++6*` You could also filter the result by "grepping" through it: `apt-cache search libstdc++6* | grep dev`

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
except that, I haven't gotten a error.

Comment: If you did _not_ receive an error back when installing that package, then the `dpkg` utility will list its content. _Does it or not?_ You apparently try to refuse an answer to that, why ever...

Comment: If you don't have a graphical environment, you can install `aptitude` (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`) -- a cool pseudo-graphical UI for `apt`. Among other, it can trivially search packages by name **using regular expressions** (so not `g++` but `g\+\+`), but in fact it has very sophisticated search capabilities using special operators (see help). It can install / remove / update packages as well, of course.